# How to wait for jQuery Ajax requests to complete from WatiN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, watin

I'm writing [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) tests to test an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) web application and have come across a timing issue with Ajax requests.

After an Ajax request is triggered by an action on the page, I'd like WatiN to wait until the request is complete before validating that the page was updated correctly.

I have a feeling that the solution will involve eval-ing [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) to register handlers for `$.ajaxStart` and `$.ajaxComplete` to track whether requests are in progress. I'll dig into that shortly, but wanted to see if anybody else has already solved this. Seems like it would be a common problem with Ajax testing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've created a few WatiN Browser extension methods to solve this problem, but am still interested in other solutions.

The `InjectAjaxMonitor` method creates a javascript global variable that attaches to the ajaxStart and ajaxComplete events to track the number of requests in progress.

Whenever you need to wait for AJAX requests to complete before moving on, you can then call `browserInstance.WaitForAjaxRequest();`.

---

```
public static class BrowserExtensions
{
    public static void WaitForAjaxRequest( this Browser browser )
    {
        int timeWaitedInMilliseconds = 0;
        var maxWaitTimeInMilliseconds = Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut*1000;

        while ( browser.IsAjaxRequestInProgress()
                && timeWaitedInMilliseconds < maxWaitTimeInMilliseconds )
        {
            Thread.Sleep( Settings.SleepTime );
            timeWaitedInMilliseconds += Settings.SleepTime;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsAjaxRequestInProgress( this Browser browser )
    {
        var evalResult = browser.Eval( "watinAjaxMonitor.isRequestInProgress()" );
        return evalResult == "true";
    }

    public static void InjectAjaxMonitor( this Browser browser )
    {
        const string monitorScript =
            @"function AjaxMonitor(){"
            + "var ajaxRequestCount = 0;"

            + "$(document).ajaxSend(function(){"
            + "    ajaxRequestCount++;"
            + "});"

            + "$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){"
            + "    ajaxRequestCount--;"
            + "});"

            + "this.isRequestInProgress = function(){"
            + "    return (ajaxRequestCount > 0);"
            + "};"
            + "}"

            + "var watinAjaxMonitor = new AjaxMonitor();";

        browser.Eval( monitorScript );
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works well unless one or more ajax requests begin before the monitor javascript is injected (at which point the counter is no longer accurate). 

I don't know how to inject the monitor earlier in the process from WatiN. It may be that the best bet is to conditionally include the monitor right after jquery is included when running tests.

Comment: I put the global ajax event handlers in my application's masterpage.  Also I only keep a semaphone bit instead of a counter: http://lebobitz.wordpress.com/2011/03/06/synchronizing-watin-and-ajax-with-jquery/

Comment: One problem with your code though - if the website doesn't have jQuery support (as in my case) - you might want to "inject it" first. Just add this code before the "monitor script". const string jquerry = @"var element1 = document.createElement('script');element1.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js';element1.type='text/javascript';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element1);";
            browser.Eval(jquerry);

Comment: in regards to @Alex comment, make sure you append the element too. `document.body.appendChild(element1);`

Answer (score 6):

This solution doesn't work very well because `.ajaxStart` is called only for the first Ajax request, while `.ajaxComplete` is called each time an ajax request is finished. if you run a this simple code in your console :

```
$.ajax({url:"/"}); $.ajax({url:"/"})
```

and add some logging in the `.ajaxStart` and `.ajaxComplete` handler methods, you can see that `.ajaxStart` handler will be called only once and `.ajaxComplete` handler twice. So `ajaxRequestCount` will become negative and all your design is screwed.

I suggest that you use `.ajaxSend` instead of `.ajaxStart` if you want to keep your design.

Another solution would be to use `.ajaxStop` instead of `.ajaxComplete`, but by doing so, you don't need the `ajaxRequestCount`, you only need a boolean that say if there are ajax requests running behind the scene.

Very useful information can be found : http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good call on the misuse of .ajaxStart. That is a bug in my solution. Using .ajaxStop would be simpler as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue myself while working on some tests using WatiN. I found that in  [version 1.1.0.4000 of WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/releasenotes-1-1-0-4000.html) (released on May 2nd 2007 (latest version being [2.0 RC2](http://watin.sourceforge.net/releasenotes-2-0-20-1089.html) from December 20th 2009)), it is claimed that better support for handling Ajax in tests were added:

> To better support testing of AJAX
>   enabled websites, this release adds
>   some more options to your toolbox.
>
> A new method is added that will wait
>   until some attribute has a certain
>   value. This might be handy in
>   situations where you need to wait
>   until a value of an element gets
>   updated.

Example:

```
// Wait until some textfield is enabled
textfield.WaitUntil("disable", false.ToSting, 10);
// Wait until some textfield is visible and enabled
textfield.WaitUntil(new Attribute("visibile", new BoolComparer(true)) && new Attribute("disabled", new BoolComparer(false)));
```

See the [link to the release notes](http://watin.sourceforge.net/releasenotes-1-1-0-4000.html) for more information.

I haven't looked into it in detail yet, so I cannot tell in which cases it might be useful or not. But thought it could be worth mentioning in case anybody else comes across this question.